# How to Convert Figma API response to FIGMA Design Code?

Tags: json, import, converters, figma, figma-api

I am using Figma API to get a document. The response is in JSON Object. I want to convert that JSON Object, so that I can copy it into Figma UI or Convert the response to a compatible import file for Figma UI. Any Ideas, How to do that ? I know it is possible because https://www.landingfolio.com/library/all/figma landing folio already does that, I inspected the website a bit but couldn't find how they did it ! So any ideas ?

I tried looking at the docs of the Figma API I couldn't find any help there ! I tried to inspect the website landingFolio, because they do it. It seems like they do the conversion at the backend and only send you the component for Figma UI.

Comment: Create a backend service that receives the Figma API response.
Parse the JSON object and convert it into a format compatible with Figma UI. This could involve transforming the data into Figma JSON, which is a specific format used by Figma.
Send the converted data to the Figma UI or provide a download link for the users.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check this plugin on Figma Community? Try this plugin **Run Plugin API**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).